Unable to invoke a dialog component via MFE
I need to load a remote module for an angular based app. The remote module is also angular based and part of another FE. Here is the code I'm using:
loadRemoteModule({
      remoteEntry: 'https://localhost:3028/sremoteEntry.js',
      remoteName: 'mfe1',
      exposedModule: './MyModule',
    })
      .then(m => {
        const myComponent= m.MyModule.ɵmod.declarations[0];
        this._dialogRef = this._dialog.open(myComponent, {
          data: eeData,
          disableClose: false,
          width: '990px',
          height: '495px',
          autoFocus: false,
        });

        return m.MyModule;
      })

The problem is  that myComponent (it has a mat-dialog in template) has this in constructor:
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData: any,
and I get error saying MdcDialogData is not provided. This could possibly due to injection token not being passed from one app to another via MFE. How to fix this?
Here is what I tried:

Having MatDialogModule in both remote and host modules
Having static MAT_DIALOG_DATA (with useValue: {}) - This works but doesn't pass eeData from host to remote.

Verified all the common deps are shared with singleton:true
